# Searching for two or more tags when using join statement and tag map

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having problems with my tag system. I have one table called ads one table called tags and another called tags_map where it links the tags to an ad listing. The problem am having is when I am searching for an ad using more than one tag.

Search parameters: php, lorem and jobs

Tags attached to the ad: jobs, php, html

SQL Query:

```
SELECT *, a.title AS ad_title, a.id AS ad_id
FROM ads AS a 
LEFT JOIN tags_map AS tm ON tm.ad_id = a.id 
LEFT JOIN tags AS t ON tm.tag_id = t.id 
WHERE a.status='live' 
AND (a.description LIKE '%php%' OR a.title LIKE '%php%' OR t.title LIKE '%php%') 
AND (a.description LIKE '%lorem%' OR a.title LIKE '%lorem%' OR t.title LIKE '%lorem%') 
AND (a.description LIKE '%jobs%' OR a.title LIKE '%jobs%' OR t.title LIKE '%jobs%') 
GROUP BY a.id 
ORDER BY bump_time DESC
```

I think the problem is with the join where it can only search for one tag can someone help

Thanks,

CP

Comment: Remind me, why are you outer joining the tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One tag cannot have a description that meets all three conditions.  However, the *set* of tags for an ad can have them.  Hence, the logic needs to move to a `having` clause:

```
SELECT *, a.title AS ad_title, a.id AS ad_id
FROM ads a LEFT JOIN
     tags_map tm
     ON tm.ad_id = a.id LEFT JOIN
     tags t
     ON tm.tag_id = t.id 
WHERE a.status='live' 
GROUP BY a.id 
HAVING SUM(a.description LIKE '%php%' OR a.title LIKE '%php%' OR t.title LIKE '%php%') > 0 AND
       SUM(a.description LIKE '%lorem%' OR a.title LIKE '%lorem%' OR t.title LIKE '%lorem%') AND
       SUM(a.description LIKE '%jobs%' OR a.title LIKE '%jobs%' OR t.title LIKE '%jobs%') 
ORDER BY bump_time DESC ;
```

Each condition in the `having` clause checks each keyword.  The `> 0` requires that the ad meets each keyword condition. The fact that some of the comparisons come from the ads table and others from the tags table is ok.  The logic will still work.

The `select *` doesn't really make sense because of the `group by`.  The fields from the `tags` and `tags_map` come from an arbitrary row -- and there may be multiple matching rows.  I would suggest this:

```
select a.*
```

If you want the tgs:

```
select a.*, group_concat(t.title) as tags
```